# Make a dynamic Link in Asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I want to make a Link dynamically in Asp.net page.

here is my aspx code:

```
  <a href='<%# String.Format("LeadInformation.aspx?refNo={0}&imgpath={1}",refno[0],imgpath[0]) %>'>
```

Aspx.cs code:

```
    public String[] imgpath = new string[8];  
    public String[] refno = new String[8];

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    imgpath[0] ="some path";
    refno[0]  = "some refno";
....
}
```

This way is not working for me. please help me to assign refNo={0}&imgpath={1} to create the link. Thank you.

Comment: Are they actually arrays, or simple strings? I would guess they are simple strings, in which case you should change `string[]` to `string` and lose the whole `= new ...` part. Then, in the aspx code, remove the brackets and indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your .aspx file:

```
<a runat="server" id="link1"></a>
```

In your code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
 imgpath[0] ="some path";
 refno[0]  = "some refno";
link1.HRef = String.Format("LeadInformation.aspx?refNo={0}&imgpath={1}",refno[0],imgpath[0]);
link1.InnerHtml = "My link";
}
```

Comment: @Aristos Have a look a this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ff86hxd.aspx

Comment: Ok, accept it, change, and remove it. (I am a man of learning and accept :)

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal: what is this `link1.InnerHtml = "My link";` use for?

Comment: InnerHtml - Gets or sets the content found between the opening and closing tags of the specified HTML server control. 
Also, you can use another property, InnerText - Gets or sets the text between the opening and closing tags of the specified HTML server control. For Eg. link1.InnerHtml = "My link"; will set the <a>My link</a>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue here you only need to change the `<%#` to `<%=`

and initialize correct the tables of array strings.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    imgpath[0] ="some path";
    refno[0]  = "some refno";
}
```